# How can I write this with where clause where CreatedDate is in between Date1var & Date2var?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I write this with where clause where CreatedDate is in between Date1var & Date2var?

```
        return _context.Logs.Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
            .Take(count)
            .Select(record => new LoggingLogic.entities.Log
            {
                DataL = record.Data,
                LogMessage = record.Message,
                CreatedDate = record.CreateDate,
                ApplicationName = record.Application.Name,
                Environment = record.Application.Environment.EnvironmentName,
                ID = record.ID
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
return _context.Logs.Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId && x.CreatedDate >= Date1Var && x.CreatedDate <= Date2Var)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
            .Take(count)
            .Select(record => new LoggingLogic.entities.Log
            {
                DataL = record.Data,
                LogMessage = record.Message,
                CreatedDate = record.CreateDate,
                ApplicationName = record.Application.Name,
                Environment = record.Application.Environment.EnvironmentName,
                ID = record.ID
            });
```

Comment: Thank you.  What if Date1Var and Date2Var are the same date?

Comment: It has the lass than or equal too so it should work too :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Where()` to `Where(x => x.ApplicationID = applicationId && x.CreatedDate >= Date1var && x.CreatedDate <= Date2var)`

I'm assuming that you want the range to be inclusive.